# What is difference between of listofIntegers.add(ValueOf(50)); and listofIntegers.add(50); in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, autoboxing

What is the difference between these 2 codes:

```
Arraylist<Integer> listofIntegers = new Arraylist<Integer>();
listofIntegers.add(666);
System.out.println("First Element of listofIntegers = " + listofIntegers.get(0));
```

And

```
Arraylist<Integer> listofIntegers = new Arraylist<Integer>();
listofIntegers.add(Integer.ValueOf(666));
System.out.println("First Element of listofIntegers = " + listofIntegers.get(0));
```

Both of them have the same output.

Thank you.

Comment: Same, you just perform boxing explicitly by calling `Integer.valueOf(...)`

Comment: Exactly the same. The compiler will turn the first into the second. Now ask what happens when you call `new Integer(666)`...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The boxing conversion uses `Integer.valueOf` implicitly, so there's no difference between the two.

For example, consider this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer x = 100;
    Integer y = Integer.valueOf(100);
}
```

The byte code for that (as shown by `javap`) is:

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: bipush        100
       2: invokestatic  #2                  // Method java/lang/Integer.valueOf:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
       5: astore_1
       6: bipush        100
       8: invokestatic  #2                  // Method java/lang/Integer.valueOf:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
      11: astore_2
      12: return
```

As you can see, the two pieces of code are identical.

Although the [language specification section on boxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7) doesn't guarantee that it will be implemented by `valueOf`, it *does* guarantee limited caching:

> If the value `p` being boxed is the result of evaluating a constant expression (§15.28) of type `boolean`, `char`, `short`, `int`, `or long`, and the result is true, false, a character in the range '\u0000' to '\u007f' inclusive, or an integer in the range -128 to 127 inclusive, then let `a` and `b` be the results of any two boxing conversions of `p`. It is always the case that `a == b`.

This is the same guarantee made by [`Integer.valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf-int-).